# jQuery serialize issue

Tags: php, jquery

Making a form submit with jquery ajax and retriving form data with serialize function. But i have a problem with links inside datastring as it converts them into something like this:

```
url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitename.com
```

but i would like to return normal link like

```
http://www.sitename.com
```

and then i dont know how to reconvert this link back inside the php final file to return it. Maybe something like to string conversion or whats the idea about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo rawurldecode("http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitename.com"); // http://www.sitename.com
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php is what you need :)